# SQL frequency of event

Tags: sql, sql-server, frequency, ssms

I've been asked to report the frequency of contacts for our clients i.e. how many of our clients are seen on a weekly, monthly, quarterly or annual basis.

When "frequency" is discussed in forums they usually refer to the number of times a certain value exists in a table.

I can get the number of contacts a client has had:-

```
select 
    A.client_ID, A.start_date, A.Months_in_Service,
    B.Contacts, (B.Contacts / A.Months_in_Service) as Contacts_per_Month_in_Service
from 
    tbl_client A 
left outer join 
    (select 
        client_ID, COUNT(contact_date) as Contacts
     from
        tbl_client_contact
     group by 
        client_ID) as B ON A.client_ID = B.client_ID
where 
    (A.end_date is null)
```

I am however struggling to incorporate the complication of distribution. For example, some clients have a lot of contacts, but though they may have had weekly contacts to start with, now they only have an annual check up.

I may to accept this is not possible, but if anyone out there has done a similar piece of work, I'd appreciate your insights.

Many thanks

Comment: You may wish to incorporate some sort of logarithmic progression.  Give the client to choose between linear and logarithmic reporting.  If logarithmic, the scale should show a more balanced frequency over time.

Comment: Can you define "weekly", etc?  Is a weekly contact one that is seen absolutely once-per-week?  Give us some parameters and show desired resultset

Comment: Admittedly I have tried to work with averages, rather than a strict must-be-seen-once-every-week.  Weekly would be 4 or more contacts per month; between 1 and 3 contacts per month would be monthly etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I'm not sure because im not able to view any sample data output. But just try this.

```
SELECT A.client_ID, A.start_date, A.Months_in_Service, B.Contacts2, 
      AVG(B.Contacts2 / A.Months_in_Service) as Contacts_per_Month_in_Service  
FROM 
(
   select Contacts, Count(Months_in_Service) as Contacts
   from tbl_client
) AS A
LEFT JOIN 
(
   select client_ID, COUNT(contact_date) as Contacts2
   from tbl_client_contact
   group by client_ID
) as B ON A.client_ID = B.client_ID
WHERE (A.end_date is null)
GROUP BY A.client_ID, A.start_date, A.Months_in_Service, 
         B.Contacts, Contacts_per_Month_in_Service
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is a solution I was playing around with, though it only works for people with a start date longer ago than a month. Perhaps this is the closest I can get to it.